# Userscript: Autofill Sharepoint User list Combobox Filter

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, userscripts, powerapps

I am trying to autofill an MS Sharepoint form with a userscript/jQuery.
The standard inputs and comboboxes are not an issue using the standard `$( selector ).val( value );` or clicking an element in the generated list. The issue arises with selecting the user from a dynamic combobox that seems to be a more complex component and not a standard combobox.
This powerapps/appmagic? field dynamically fetches the user list based on a filter value entered into an input field. I have tried setting the input field using `.val( value )` and `.attr( 'value', value )` as well as manually filling the span fields displayed when the input is hidden. I have attempted manually triggering the change, keyup, keydown, keypress and input events on the input field and document, but the dynamic list is not populated or displayed to allow me to select an item from it. If I manually add or remove a letter to the filter after my pre-populated value, it works as expected so something behaves differently when I dynamically populate the input field.

Under the DOM inspector, the reactive event seems to be document.input as disabling this stops the population of the combobox under any condition.

Does anyone have experience with these fields and know how I can dynamically populate this input and have the list generate?

Answer (score 0):

Is it like you want to dynamically populate UserList combobox based on an input entered in an input field or if this is not the right understanding,could you be more precise in the explanation.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your interest! Yes, when you click on the field an input replaces the previous element which accepts text to filter the results. When I set the value of the input programmatically the list elements are not displayed, but manual typing the same value in the same input does display results. I can't seem to find a demo page or I would share it and the page I'm using requires authentication. Based on some research it may be a "People Picker Control"

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try setting the **Items** property of UserList combobox as

```
    Filter(comboboxlist,enteredvaluecolumn = Inputfield.Text)
```

where **comboboxlist** is the list used to populate the combobox,
      **enteredvaluecolumn** is the column in comboboxlist corresponding to the entered value in the input field and
      **Inputfield** is the input field.

Comment: I'm trying to fill the form from the user's side with a userscript. The comboboxlist elements are generated dynamically via ajax after the filter value is processed by the site's script(s). My issue is the filter value is never reacted upon to fetch the filtered list.